# Show custom view (buttons) below the EditText as soon as user starts typing... Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, autocompletetextview, android-custom-view

I want to show few buttons below the `EditText` as soon as use starts typing something in `EditText` like shown below:

[image]

### before

[image]

### after

any comments/help would be appreciated :) I think it is similar to `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this...

edittext_id.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                      //This method will call when you type somthing on edittext
                set visibility of your buttons here.
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put all the buttons inside a LinearLayout, set an ID for it in your xml file and set it to be invisible. Then register a listener for the EditText and once it's populated with text, set the visibility of LinearLayout to true.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE

Comment: That's what I was thinking but it would drag the whole existing GUI down, don't you think? Whereas in many apps these buttons are drawn on top of existing GUI... 
Thanks for help, I will try this too...

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by "drag the whole existing GUI down"

Comment: Means I do not want to change an existing main layout by making thing visible or invisible at run time, instead I want to show some popup dialog right below `EditText`. I ended up writing my own Popup windows that slides down nicely from the `EditText` in header and sticks there unless user press back button etc... I will share my code in few days. :)

Comment: I guess this popup windows is also being used in Android OS, so called "Quick Actions".